# Непонятная ошибка в JS

Tags: javascript

```
function range(from, to) {
        var massive = [];
        var x = 0;
        for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            massive[x] = i;
            x++;
        }
        return massive;
    }

    function sum(range(1, 10)) {
        for (i = 0; i <= range.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + range[i];
            console.log(sum);
        }
    }
```

Консоль находит ошибку во второй функции при её вызове.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример:

```js
    function range(from, to) {
     var arr = [];
        for (var i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
        return arr;
    }
    
    function sum() {
     var arr = range(1, 10);
        var sum = 0;
    
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + arr[i];
        }
     console.log(sum);
    }
    sum();
```

> 55

В JS нет такого понятия, как именованный массив (это не PHP), есть либо массив, либо объект (в данном случае самым удачным словом вместо "объекта" будет "хеш").

По этой причине в данном случае держать отдельный счетчик для индексов не нужно.

Ну а вызов функции при декларации другой функции это почти криминал.

В JS допустимо передавать функции в качестве параметров (для последующего использования внутри функции, в которую вы передаете такую функцию), но без invoking, т.е. без ее вызова:

```
function myFunc() {
    alert('test');
}

function anotherFunc(callMe) {
    callMe();
}
anotherFunc(myFunc);
```

Comment: Можете пояснить что за загадочный последний элемент массива из за которого цикл for выдает нужный результат только при условии i < arr.length, а в противном случае выдает NaN?

Comment: @brachkoff не уверен, что до конца понял Ваш вопрос, но видимо речь идет о втором цикле. Счетчик начинается с 0 и до arr.length. Этим обеспечивается поочередный проход по массиву. Если i вдруг станет равен значению не в диапазоне 0 < i < arr.length, то вы будете обращаться к несуществующему элементу массива. Обращение к несуществующему элементу массива возвращает 'undefined'. Сложение 'undefined' и числа дают NaN, потому что интерпретатор не может привести такое выражение к численному.

Comment: @brachkoff Наверное еще важно отметить, что индексы элементов в массиве тоже начинаются с 0, а не с 1. Поэтому мы i ставим в 0, чтобы получить первый элемент массива. Потом увеличиваем до 1, чтобы получить второй и так далее, пока не пройдем все элементы

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(range(1, 10)){....}
```

В скобках при определении функции должны передаваться параметры, а вы делаете вычисления...
правильно:

```
function sum(ar){....}
```

а уже при вызове можно и вычисления:

```
s = sum(range(1, 10));
```